# SUBSTRING AND CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to put "Goal Rate of Infusion:  ###" into it's own field

I'm trying this code Substring(SummaryLine, CHARINDEX('Infusion: ',summaryline),+14) but it's not working.

```
, Initial Rate:  40, Goal Rate of Infusion:  0, to goal rate in 8 hours
, Initial Rate:  30, Goal Rate of Infusion:  0, to goal rate in 8 hours
, Initial Rate:  10, Goal Rate of Infusion:  10, to goal rate in 8 hours, HOLD FOR N/V
, Initial Rate:  40, Goal Rate of Infusion:  10, to goal rate in 8 hours
, Initial Rate:  40, Goal Rate of Infusion:  10, to goal rate in 8 hours
, Initial Rate:  100, Goal Rate of Infusion:  100, to goal rate in 8 hours
, Initial Rate:  15, Goal Rate of Infusion:  15, to goal rate in 8 hours
, Initial Rate:  40, Goal Rate of Infusion:  15, to goal rate in 8 hours
```

Comment: show your current code, so we can fix it for you.

Comment: "it's not working" is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: Substring(SummaryLine, CHARINDEX('Infusion: ',summaryline),+14) AS NewSummaryField  Infusion:  50,
Infusion:  55,
Infusion:  65,
Infusion:  40,
Infusion:  70,
Infusion:  50,
Infusion:  50,
Infusion:  40,

Comment: I get "Infusion: 50", or Infusion: 100 (no comma)

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information. Have you tried putting 'Goal Rate of Infusion' into your CHARINDEX function instead of 'Infusion' then adjusting the offset of 14?

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm going to work on that, it did give me better results before but then I thought maybe there was an easier solution.  It doesn't look like it from the responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SummaryLine,
    StartIdx,
    EndIdx,
    CONVERT(
        int,
        SUBSTRING( SummaryLine, StartIdx, EndIdx - StartIdx )
    ) AS InfusionRate
FROM (
    SELECT
        SummaryLine,
        StartIdx,
        CHARINDEX(',', summaryLine, StartIdx) AS EndIdx
    FROM (
        SELECT
            SummaryLine,
            CHARINDEX('Infusion:', SummaryLine) + 10 AS StartIdx,
        FROM
            SourceTable
    )
)
```

Or as a single line:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(
        int,
        SUBSTRING(
            SummaryLine,
            CHARINDEX('Infusion:', summaryLine) + 10,
            CHARINDEX(
                ',',
                SummaryLine,
                CHARINDEX('Infusion:', summaryLine) + 10
            )
        )
    )
FROM
    SourceTable
```

SQL does not allow you to cache or alias expression results in a single `SELECT` statement, unfortunately - you need to either use a subquery (the first example) or repeat the expression (2nd example).

UPDATE: I did some research, you could use `CROSS APPLY` to compute `StartIdx` only once:

```
SELECT
    SummaryLine,
    CONVERT(
        int,
        SUBSTRING(
            SummaryLine,
            StartIdx,
            CHARINDEX(',', summaryLine, StartIdx) - StartIdx
        )
    ) AS InfusionRate
FROM
    SourceTable
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT CHARINDEX('Infusion:', summaryLine) + 10 AS StartIdx
    )
```